# Building Products with Maven

Tags: maven-2

I'm fairly new to Maven and I'd like to use it to build a multi-module project.

Lets assume I have the following svn repository structure:

```
 - /trunk/common-services/login-service
   (.jar) [re-usable components]  
 - /trunk/services/mybusiness-service
   (.jar)
 - /trunk/webservices/mybusiness-rest
   (.war) 
 - /trunk/products/myproduct
   (pom) [issue mvn command here]
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to checkout and build the entire "product" from a single pom using a single mvn command (from a developers pov as well as a CI pov). It's safe to assume that I have the trunk checked out.

How do I do this using Maven? I've looked at the Maven reactor plugin, but I can't figure out how to use it correctly (if it is the correct plugin to use).

Answer (score 0):

The reactor plugin assumes each module has its `pom.xml`.

For your use case, you would want to create a `pom.xml` for each module (`login-service`, `mybusiness-service` and `mybusiness-rest`).  You would specify the `dependencies` in each of the modules. For instance, if your `mybusiness-rest` depends on `login-service` and `mybusiness-service`, you would specify these projects as `dependencies`.

You would have a `pom.xml` in `/trunk` which specifies each of the modules to be built. You can use the reactor features in this pom.xml to determine, when to build (or not build) specific modules.

Your developers and CI can build using this *single* pom.